# New control transfer statements (labels) for Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

What would be the best practices for the new [control transfer statements](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID135) (labels) in `Swift 2`?

Since I hear about it I can't stop compare it with the `goto` command from the good and old `Basic` language, what never was well accepted from experient programmers at the time.

Some uses of the control flow transfer looks ok, like in example below:

```
outer: for i in 1...100{
  for j in 1...100{
    print("\(i), \(j)")
    if j == 10 {
      break outer
    }
  }
}
```

But what are the limitations for the control flow transfer use?

When start to be bad practice to use it?

If its use was such a bad practice why it is back?

Comment: That is some seriously garbled English there dude, to the point that it's quite hard to figure out what you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry I speak 3 languages sometimes is hard to not get confuse. I will try to clarify!

Comment: @DuncanC I re-edit it I hope its easier to understand now.

Comment: By label do you mean [`control flow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120)?

Answer (score 3):

You can prefix a loop statement, an if statement, or a switch statement with a statement label followed  by a colon (:) ,break and continue statements are used to change control flow in a loop statement or a switch statement.

break statement breaks the current loop execution where as continue just breaks current iteration.

consider:

```
     firstLoop :for j in 0...1{
      secondLoop: for i in 0...10{
        if (i % 2) == 0{
          if (i == 4){
             break firstLoop
          }
          print(i)
         }
       }
      }
```

Output will be :  **0,2**

If we replace **break firstloop** by **break secondLoop** o/p Will be: **0,2,0,2**

If we replace **break firstloop** by **continue** o/p Will be: **0,2,6,8,10,0,2,6,8,10**

If we replace **break firstloop** by **continue firstloop** continue o/p Will be again : **0,2,0,2**

If continue is followed by a statement label then it will stop the current iteration of that statement label not the loop pointed by statement label.

**goto VS statement label**

> . goto is a kind of unconditional branching ,where you can branch anywhere in the program,The goto statement is discouraged , because it alters the sequential flow of logic .

**Why statement Label** is used and what is it's **Limitation**?

> . where as continue and break can make use of statement label if and only if it is written inside the loop which has same statement label which it is using so the code will be more safer. It makes programers life easy , off course you can't directly branch out to any part of program using continue,break and statement Label it can be considered as a limitation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, I already play with the new labels in Swift 2 and of course I used a lot the command goto when I start development, but my question was a bit more about is that a good strategy? will it create better codes or more hack codes? Will people start to create loops inside loops instead abstract it just because they can?

Comment: My pleasure !! as I have told you, using statement label is safer than using goto , it will change control flow with respect to the loop in which you have written continue or break , but goto can bring you in any part of the program, so statement labels are better than goto(safety) . I think it will create better code  if there are less number of loops  & statement labels  or else it will become hard to keep an eye on all statement labels .

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking about using labels for break and continue statements. That is a much more limited, safer use than the horrible goto statements from basic. It simply lets you tell the compiler the scope you need to break out of/continue when you have nested looping constructs.

As far as I know break and continue is the only use of labels in Swift, and for that it seems useful and appropriate.

Comment: You right, the example I saw was referring to loops, but seems that you can break to any part of the function.