# Way to break out of an inner For loop in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop

Is there a simple way to break out of an inner For loop, i.e. a Fro loop within another For loop? Without having to set additional flags for example

Comment: why you don't use a while loop ?

Comment: additional flag is the simplest way in many languages. Sometimes there is a different solution but we would have to see the loop.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768931/new-control-transfer-statements-labels-for-swift-2-0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are three basic methods:

1. Using an additional boolean flag
2. Using a labelled loop (`label: for ...`) and then `break label`
3. Extracting the loops into a separate function/method and then using a `return` instead of a `break`.

From code quality perspective I believe 3. is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, used the labelled outerLoop approach

Answer (score 35):

You just need to name your loop. Like this:

```
   let array = [1,2,3]

   for number in 1...6 {

        innerLoop: for i in array {

            let newNumber = i + number

            if i == 2 {

                break innerLoop
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great answer! I had a loop(3) inside a loop(2) inside a dictionary loop(1) and once I found the value in (3) I was able to easily stop the dictionary loop (1). Thanks